# Write File Python

Tags: python, file, cgi

I have a python script I am running with a post request. The script is located in my cgi-bin and at the end of the script I am trying to upload a file to the `/var/www/html/` folder and I am doing it like this

```
myFile= open("/var/www/html/file.html","w")
myFile.write("<html><body><p>test</p></body></html>")
myFile.close()
```

But I keep getting

```
<type 'exceptions.IOError'>: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/var/www/html/file.html'
```

What is going wrong?

Comment: Are you developing on Linux or IO?

Comment: the server is running Centos, so Linux

Comment: I saw your comment below about permissions so you are on the right path.  Still you need to make sure file.html has the same permissions to read and write. Check the folder permission there.  If you have, check to see if the file.html is open in another process.  You might be fighting for writing rights.

Comment: @EricThomas does it all need to be 777?

Comment: At least 6 because that is equal to rw- and that is the permission you need to write to.

Answer (score 1):

The error itself is already clear, your don't have enough permission to write to `/var/www/html`. It might be related the owner of the directory. If the owner is another user, then your current user don't have the write permission to the directory, the error would occur.

Comment: the cgi-bin is 755 so is my python script?

Comment: Updated the answer. Does `var/www/html` owned by a different user, like `apache` or something?

Comment: Right so I think it might be owned by apache, but I know its bad but just to try I changed var, www, cgi-bin to 777 and it still didn't work do it matter the permission of the cgi-bin or of the html folder